# taglib not detected in JSP when using Sitemesh

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, sitemesh

Normally this is how I create my JSP file

```
<html>
 <head>
  <%@ include file="initDirectives.jsp"%>
  <%@ include file="header-site.jsp"%>
  <title><spring:message code="menu.about.us" /></title>
 </head>
 <body>
      aboutttttttt.
 </body>
</html>
```

I was hoping to be able to remove the 2 inclusion of my JSP Files on my pages, which are:

1. `initDirectives.jsp` which contains code something like `<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>` and so on
2. `header-site.jsp` which contains the header for menu links on my pages

After I configured my Sitemesh configuration, I created `default.jsp` as follow

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="decorator"
    uri="http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/decorator"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<%@ include file="../views/initDirectives.jsp"%>
<%@ include file="../views/header-site.jsp"%>
<title><decorator:title default="DNA G2" /></title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<decorator:head />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container clear-top">
        <decorator:body />
        <br>
        <div id="footer">
            <div class="container">
                <p class="muted credit">© 2013 DNA G2. All Rights Reserved.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally, this is what my JSP page contains

```
<head>
<title><spring:message code="menu.about.us" /></title>
</head>
<body>aboutttttttt.
</body>
```

The issue is the `spring:message` tag is not recognized anymore. What did I miss here ?

Answer (score 0):

To use spring:message your project must include the following bean in your applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="messageSource"  
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">  
    <property name="basename" value="messages"/>  
  </bean>
```

(your messages now will be stored in a file called: messages_en.properties (for English language), messages_lt.properties (for Lithuanian language) etc.)

Then make sure your JSP page contains Spring's taglib (example taken from my project):

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>**


<html>
<head>
.....
```

Add spring-core JAR into your project.

Or you can also take a look at this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Can I declare the `taglib` code within the decorator itself ? Or the only way is to include that code within every JSP file I create ?

Comment: You can make an universal taglib library and include it into every page like this: http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/Web.xml.TagLib . Or the easiest thing (as you said) is to include the code in every JSP file :)

Comment: So basically the code would be duplicated everywhere. Seems like there's no way for me to declare it once and all pages / JSP can retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the taglib include statements before `<html>` in your default.jsp.

Comment: I tried including both `taglib` and `%@ include file="initDirectives.jsp"%>` before `<html>` however I am still unable to access the `taglib`.